# PHP - SQL: mostrar o e-mail do usuário pelo banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Galera, é o seguinte:
Feito o registro do usuário no site, ele salva no banco de dados (óbvio).

Esse é o código da conexão com o banco de dados (está correto?):

```
<?php      
echo $sql= "select *  from users order by email";
$rs =mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die ("Consulta nao realizada");
?>
```

A dúvida é como fazer para o banco pegar apenas o e-mail do usuário ativo e não mostrar o e-mail de todos os usuários do site.

Quero mostrar o e-mail do usuário ativo com um "echo $email" e não sei onde e como fazer para aparecer.

Obrigado!

Comment: Esse código está obsoleto só.

Comment: Como assim? É que eu não sei como "capturar" apenas o email do usuario ativo e mostrá-lo a página.

Comment: Quando vc faz login, imagino q vc deva guardar essas informações na sessão, certo?

Comment: sim, ele guarda em users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar [PDO](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-conectar-mysql-com-php-via-pdo/30317), as funções nativas do MySQL para o PHP estão decraptadas a anos.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta, não é necessário o segundo parâmetro. Considerando que uma conexão com o banco de dados está aberta basta utilizar

```
$query = mysql_query('select *  from users order by email');
```

E para retornar os dados basta utilizar o [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Recomendo ler a documentação completa do mysql_query [clicando aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Valeu Vinicios! Depois de adicionar apenas esse código que você mandou, ele aparece tudo na mesma linha, tipo admin senhadoadmin... um do lado do outro, e eu só queria que mostrasse o email do usuário ativo.

Comment: 2. Agora ele só aparece os emails adicionados por todos os usuários cadastrados, eu queria que mostrasse apenas o email do usuário logado

Comment: Use um `where id = id_usuario_logado` em sua consulta com sugeriu o @Filiwoe

Answer (score 0):

recomendo utilizar sessions
voce terá que fazer a consultar Mysql filtrando o id do usuário que logou.

```
$sql = "Select email from users where id = $id"; //id = a chave primária da tabela de usuarios
$query = @mysql_query($sql);
$resultado = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

feito isso agora é criar a session e definir seu valor

```
$_SESSION['usuarioID'] = $resultado['id']; //exemplo de outros dados que queira
$_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
```

para mostrar o email

```
$pEmail = $_SESSION['email']; 

echo $pEmail;
```

Comment: Valeu Filipe, ajudou bastante!